# Troubleshooting GWT with white (blank) screen

Tags: java, gwt, screen

I'm using uiBinder and if I want to have Google Maps widget and suggestbox on the ui template I just get blank screen with nothing loading. Everything compiles OK. I have tested all the permutations in all the important browsers and it is the same thing everywhere.

Any idea on how to approach this in order to figure out what is breaking the javascript?

Comment: Any errors in browser console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It possibly sounds like a runtime exception has been thrown before any UI controls were rendered.

As a simple test make the very first line in the client be a Window.alert(). If you get an alert box then run the app in the GWT Shell to see the ex stack trace. If you don't get an alert then the GWT app isn't loading. Try running in Firefox with FireBug's Net monitor enabled. This should let you see why the relevant JS files, etc aren't being loaded.

Answer (score 1):

Having a nocache.js in the .html page that doesn't match the project creates a white screen. Try this if the alert code mentioned in this thread doesn't work.